# Dropdown menus do not act as expected using Angular UI Bootstrap Navbar & UI-Router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-bootstrap

We have an Angular site using UI Bootstrap & UI-Router

When in collapsed mode, if you click any open with a drop down, the menu re-collapses before the user can see the dropdown options.

**Here's a plunker:**

https://plnkr.co/edit/73s4kuFR2c9EuhMd6G4l

```
.... Why is SO making me paste code if I have a plunkr link ?? 
See plunker link for code example.
```

What am I overlooking?

-Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You must remove `ng-click="navCollapsed = true"` from your `div.collapse.navbar-collapse`

It should look like this:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" ng-class="!navCollapsed && 'in'">
```

It will stop the wrong behavior.

Comment: Ty for your input @klauskpm.  Changing out that line does alter the behavior, and maybe there is actually 2 issues here.  But when I change out the line you posted, while the menu doesn't collapse anymore, the embedded drop-down doesn't open either.

Comment: Klauskpm was partially correct in that his suggestion prevented the parent menu from undesirably collapsing.  However, the `uib-dropdown` directive was also required to make sure the embedded drop downs work as well.